# Django: Form method is_valid() always return FALSE

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to make a Django app. But i have this problem. the method is_valid() always return FALSE. Maybe the problem is in the forms.py in the tipoAtributo field because when i commented it, the problem its solved. but i need to use this MultipleChoiceField.

forms.py

```
class tipoAtribute(forms.Form):
  nombreAtribute = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
  CHOICES = (
    ('Categorico', 'Categorico'),
    ('NUMERICO', 'NUMERICO'))
  tipoAtributo = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = CHOICES, required=True, widget=forms.Select())
```

views.py

```
def createTables(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = tipoAtribute(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "Soy una bandera boba"
        nombreAtribute = form.cleaned_data['nombreAtribute']
        tipoAtributo = form.cleaned_data['tipoAtributo']
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("use " + nombreProyecto)
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE "+ nombreProyecto + "(prueba VARCHAR(25))")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see why it's not valid by print errors:

```
def createTables(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = tipoAtribute(request.POST) # No need for "or None"
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
    else:
        print form.errors
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use the `Select` widget with a `MultipleChoiceField`. Use [`SelectMultiple`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple) instead.

```
tipoAtributo = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=True, widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
```